# How to make a bootstrap form with columns within a modal?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I have a form that I am trying to create within a modal but I cannot seem to get the columns to lineup within the modal like on the main page. When I tried using CSS the layout broke down when the page got smaller. I have a plunker of what I have tried: http://plnkr.co/edit/TavZzzzxwgPoy7qOdOAt?p=preview

```
      CSS used:         
      .ticketList {
       display: table-cell;
       width: auto;
       text-align: center;
       }
```

[image]

Comment: Can you tell, what is the exact error?

Comment: There is no error in the code. I am trying to use the 12 column system to create the form you see above. What I don't know is if a modal has the same 12 column structure as bootstrap has for the main page. When I tried using it like I did on the main page my ui list is not lining up.

Comment: check the link : http://plnkr.co/edit/7uTL4FrBVqvMEvzcgT0W?p=preview

Comment: Yes, but I want to make sure I understand... So inside the modal their is a 12 column layout?

Comment: yes. you can use grid system anywhere

Comment: That's amazing!!! Bootstraps grid system is really something especially now that I know you can use it in other situations other then the main page. Thank you for the commits and for the explanation. Clarity is beautiful especially when it comes to coding. Many thanks!!!